# What are these .xauth files for in my home directory?

Tags: fedora, xauth

I don't recognize these files from previous Fedora versions (On 35 now):

```
-rw-------. 1 1000 1000  100 Nov 15 21:49 .xauthHhCXrs
-rw-------. 1 1000 1000  100 Nov 14 22:35 .xauthmDNgLB
```

Both contain at least this string in common:

```
fedoraMIT-MAGIC-COOKIE
```

and they also contain some unwritable characters (?)s

I see some people get errors from ssh or xterms containing this string but I'm not using either of those services yet on this build. The files appeared on their own.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37157097/829970

Comment: @MosheKatz Thanks but the thing is I haven't used xterm on the system. Do you know why these files were generated?